# hibernate.cfg.xml is read only when deprecated buildSessionFactory() is used and not with StandardServiceRegistryBuilder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am beginning to learn hibernate and facing a very strange issue.I have set up my `hibernate.cfg.xml` inside `src/main/resources`. When i create my session factory using the deprecated `configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory()`, the xml is read and the program runs. But when i use the supported `configuration.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build());`, the xml is not read and it throws an error.

HibernateUtil.class

```
package com.infiniteskills.data;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.Service;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try
        {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            //return configuration.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build());
            return configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("There was an error building the factory");
        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances</property>
    <property name="connection.username">infinite</property>
    <property name="connection.password">skills</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

log when i use the supported version version
[image]
[image]

logs when i use the deprecated version
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The logs are not readable.

Comment: I can zoom in easily

Comment: It seems company proxy is the cause of my access pb sorry

Comment: You say you are starting to learn Hibernate. Why then do you use deprecated apis and old hibernate.cfg.xml? Maybe you should take a tutorial. Do you want to use Spring Boot as well?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i am following  a tutorial. It is a bit old, so it shows both xml and . properties method